# How to packed another js file using Webpack5?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, frontend, webpack-5

I am a newcomer to webpack.

I have 2 javascript files and I want to use one as the entry file. For another I don't want all the html use it, I'll use it in some specify files.

For exmaple, as you can see the file structure below ,`main.js` is my entry file. And there is another js file called `123.js`. I expect that `1.html` uses both `main.js` and `123.js`. However, the `./2.html` only need `./main.js

`File Structure:`

```
./main.js
./123.js
./1.html
./2.html
```

How to implement this？
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/)

Your webpack configuration could look something like this:

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './main.js',
    oneTwoThree: './123.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: '1.html',
      chunks: ['main', 'oneTwoThree']
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: '2.html',
      chunks: ['main']
    })
  ],
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```